# How to get rid of unnecessary(?) code - adjusting to DRY principle

Tags: java, dry, solid-principles

I was with the similiar topic some time ago. I'm looking at my app and I think it has a lot of unnecessary code. What I mean is I have service that is responsible for scraping data from different categories of books from two bookstores. Right now I have 5 categories so I have 5 methods, but what if I'm gonna add some new categories? I will have to add more methods... and I think it is not a good option. Right now it looks like this:

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/romances")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15RomanticBooks() {
        return categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromRomanceCategory();
    }

    @GetMapping("/biographies")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BiographiesBooks() {
        return categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromBiographiesCategory();
    }

    @GetMapping("/guides")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15GuidesBooks() {
        return categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromGuidesCategory();
    }

    @GetMapping("/fantasy")
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15FantasyBooks() {
        return categorizedBookService.get15BooksFromFantasyCategory();
    }
```

and here I was thinking about

```
@GetMapping("/{category}")
public Map<......> get 15BooksFromCategory(@PathVariable CategoryType category)
{...}
```

I think this is the best way, but it is harder with service.

Service for it looks like this:

```
package bookstore.scraper.book.scrapingtypeservice;

import bookstore.scraper.enums.Bookstore;
import bookstore.scraper.book.Book;
import bookstore.scraper.fetcher.empik.EmpikFetchingBookService;
import bookstore.scraper.fetcher.merlin.MerlinFetchingBookService;
import bookstore.scraper.urlproperties.EmpikUrlProperties;
import bookstore.scraper.urlproperties.MerlinUrlProperties;
import bookstore.scraper.utilities.JSoupConnector;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class CategorizedBookService {

    private final EmpikFetchingBookService empikBookService;
    private final MerlinFetchingBookService merlinFetchingBookService;
    private final EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties;
    private final MerlinUrlProperties merlinUrlProperties;
    private final JSoupConnector jSoupConnector;

    @Autowired
    public CategorizedBookService(EmpikFetchingBookService empikBookService, MerlinFetchingBookService merlinFetchingBookService, EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties, MerlinUrlProperties merlinUrlProperties, JSoupConnector jSoupConnector) {
        this.empikBookService = empikBookService;
        this.merlinFetchingBookService = merlinFetchingBookService;
        this.empikUrlProperties = empikUrlProperties;
        this.merlinUrlProperties = merlinUrlProperties;
        this.jSoupConnector = jSoupConnector;
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromRomanceCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getRomances(), merlinUrlProperties.getMerlin().getRomances());
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromFantasyCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getFantasy(), merlinUrlProperties.getMerlin().getFantasy());
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromCrimeCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getCrime(), merlinUrlProperties.getMerlin().getCrime());
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromGuidesCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getGuides(), merlinUrlProperties.getMerlin().getGuides());
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFromBiographiesCategory() {
        return get15BooksFrom(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getBiographies(), merlinUrlProperties.getMerlin().getBiographies());
    }

    private Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksFrom(String bookStoreEmpikURL, String bookStoreMerlinURL) {
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks = new EnumMap<>(Bookstore.class);

        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, empikBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(jSoupConnector.connect(bookStoreEmpikURL)));
        bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, merlinFetchingBookService
                .get15BooksFromCategory(jSoupConnector.connect(bookStoreMerlinURL)));

        return bookstoreWith15CategorizedBooks;
    }
}
```

I have to pass 2 different links depend on which category was called. Is there any way to do this?

`EmpikBookService/merlinFetchingBookService` are services that use Jsoup to **scrape** data.

```
package bookstore.scraper.fetcher.empik;

import bookstore.scraper.book.Book;
import bookstore.scraper.urlproperties.EmpikUrlProperties;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@Service
public class EmpikFetchingBookService {

    private static final int FIRST_PART_PRICE = 0;
    private static final int SECOND_PART_PRICE = 1;

    private static final int BESTSELLERS_NUMBER_TO_FETCH = 5;
    private static final int CATEGORIZED_BOOKS_NUMBER_TO_FETCH = 15;
    private static final String DIV_PRODUCT_WRAPPER = "div.productWrapper";
    private static final String DATA_PRODUCT_ID = "data-product-id";

    private final EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties;

    @Autowired
    public EmpikFetchingBookService(EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties) {
        this.empikUrlProperties = empikUrlProperties;
    }

    public Book getMostPreciseEmpikBook(Document document) {
        String author = document.select("div.smartAuthorWrapper.ta-product-smartauthor").select("a").first().text();
        String price = convertEmpikPriceWithPossibleDiscountToActualPrice(document.select("div.price.ta-price-tile").first().text());
        String title = document.select(DIV_PRODUCT_WRAPPER).select("strong").first().text();
        String productID = document.select(DIV_PRODUCT_WRAPPER).select("a").first().attr(DATA_PRODUCT_ID);
        String bookUrl = createBookURL(title, productID);

        return Book.builder()
                .author(author)
                .price(price)
                .title(title)
                .productID(productID)
                .bookURL(bookUrl).build();
    }

    public List<Book> get5BestSellersEmpik(Document document) {
        List<Element> siteElements = document.select(DIV_PRODUCT_WRAPPER);
        List<Book> empikBestSellers = new ArrayList<>();

        IntStream.range(0, BESTSELLERS_NUMBER_TO_FETCH)
                .forEach(iteratedElement -> {

                    String author = siteElements.get(iteratedElement).select("div.smartAuthorWrapper.ta-product-smartauthor").select("a").first().text();
                    String price = convertEmpikPriceWithPossibleDiscountToActualPrice(siteElements.get(iteratedElement).select("div.price.ta-price-tile").first().text());
                    String title = siteElements.get(iteratedElement).select("strong").first().ownText();
                    String productID = siteElements.get(iteratedElement).select(DIV_PRODUCT_WRAPPER).select("a").first().attr(DATA_PRODUCT_ID);
                    String bookUrl = createBookURL(title, productID);

                    empikBestSellers.add(Book.builder()
                            .author(author)
                            .price(price)
                            .title(title)
                            .productID(productID)
                            .bookURL(bookUrl)
                            .build());
                });
        return empikBestSellers;
    }

    public List<Book> get15BooksFromCategory(Document document) {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Element> siteElements = document.select("div.productBox__info");

        IntStream.range(0, CATEGORIZED_BOOKS_NUMBER_TO_FETCH)
                .forEach(iteratedElement -> {

                    String author = executeFetchingAuthorProcess(siteElements, iteratedElement);
                    String price = convertEmpikPriceWithPossibleDiscountToActualPrice(siteElements.get(iteratedElement).select("div.productBox__price").first().text());
                    String title = siteElements.get(iteratedElement).select("span").first().ownText();
                    String productID = siteElements.get(iteratedElement).select("a").first().attr(DATA_PRODUCT_ID);
                    String bookUrl = createBookURL(title, productID);

                    books.add(Book.builder()
                            .author(author)
                            .price(price)
                            .title(title)
                            .productID(productID)
                            .bookURL(bookUrl)
                            .build());
                });

        return books;
    }

    private String convertEmpikPriceWithPossibleDiscountToActualPrice(String price) {
        String[] splittedElements = price.split("\\s+");
        return splittedElements[FIRST_PART_PRICE] + splittedElements[SECOND_PART_PRICE];
    }

    private String createBookURL(String title, String productID) {
        return String.format(empikUrlProperties.getEmpik().getConcreteBook(), title, productID);
    }

    //method is required as on empik site, sometimes occurs null for author and we need to change code for fetching
    private static String executeFetchingAuthorProcess(List<Element> siteElements, int i) {
        String author;
        Element authorElements = siteElements.get(i).select("span > a").first();
        if (authorElements != null)
            author = authorElements.ownText();
        else
            author = siteElements.get(i).select("> span > span").first().text();
        return author;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't modify the services to accept `CategoryType`?

Comment: @shmosel I dont understand. I need to pass good url's based on category type which make it hard for me. I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) The name `get15BooksFromCategory(CategoryType)` is not right: you are hardcoding a number of books to be returned into the method name.

Today you return 15, tomorrow you would need to return 20, on Sundays you may need to return 5, for Andrews you may need to return 50. You get the point.

Consider these signatures.

```
getAllBooksFromCategory(CategoryType);
getNBooksFromCategory(CategoryType, Integer);
```

(2) Get rid of these fields in the service.

```
private final EmpikUrlProperties empikUrlProperties;
private final MerlinUrlProperties merlinUrlProperties;
private final JSoupConnector jSoupConnector;
```

The first two are parts of `EmpikFetchingBookService` and `MerlinFetchingBookService`, respectively. `JSoupConnector` is a more low-level abstraction and it shouldn't appear at this level. It may reside in a common parent of those book services or be a separate `JSoupService` that the common parent is dependent on.

(3) Ideally, you should end up with a very simple service which has a single responsibility - to collect books from its sources.

```
 class BookService {
      private List<BookServiceSource> sources;

      public Map<String, List<Book>> getBooksByCategory(Category category) {
          return sources.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(BookServiceSource::getName, 
                  source -> source.getBooksByCategory(category)));
      }
 }
```

`BookServiceSource` has a similar interface as `BookService` does. However, `MerlinSource`, as a subclass of `BookServiceSource`, doesn't the delegate the job to others. Instead, it prepares an URL and gives it to the `JSoupService`.

The responsibility of a `BookServiceSource` is to prepare request parameters and transform the result returned from the `JSoupService` into a `List<Book>`. Since each bookstore has a different DOM, you need to know how a particular DOM can be mapped into your structure.

```
interface BookServiceSource {
    String getName();
    List<Book> getBooksByCategory(Category category);
}

class MerlinSource implements BookServiceSource {
    private JSoupService service;
    private MerlinUrlProperties properties;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
      return "merlin";
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getBooksByCategory(Category category) {
      // at this point, we have both 
      // JSoupService (to make a real request) and 
      // MerlinUrlProperties (to prepare everything for that request)
    }
}
```

Think of the `MerlinUrlProperties` as a utility that can give a mapping between the category and a URL to books from that category.

`MerlinUrlProperties` could be a `Map` itself if it contains nothing but a bunch of methods that return URLs. The point is you don't have to define a new method for a new category and force everybody who uses your API to change themselves in order to include a new part of the API. With a `Map` or enum, the interface would be more stable.

```
Map<String, String> categoryToMarlinURL = new HashMap<>();

categoryToMarlinURL.put("horror", "marlin.com/horror");
categoryToMarlinURL.put("drama", "marlin.com/drama");
```

You have everything you need:

- the category (`category`),
- the URL to that category (`categoryToMarlinURL.get(category)`),
- the service that makes requests (`jSoupService.connect(categoryToMarlinURL.get(category))`).

Comment: 2) It still make me confused, cuz I need somehow to give proper link based on given category, which all question is about

Comment: @mara122 we'll get to it. Forget about links at `BookService` level. I think it is a different level of abstraction...

Comment: I think the problem is I looked at this so many times that I can not get idea about something completely diffrent so I need sample of good way how it should be done.  I have updated question with EmpikFetchingBookService with a method responsible for scraping data from given Document and here (I think) I should have some kind of system that would choose good link for given category. 3) It would be what I want, but...

Comment: I don't know wheter this way is good in EmpikFetching/MerlinFetching. But I don't think so, because if I would have 10 categories, then this method is so long. https://gist.github.com/must1/e992a859589554b8025e9aa6e3eccc27

Comment: @mara122 I am trying to drag you down from the highest point of abstraction (a general service method) to the lowest (a request via jsop). Updated the code, have a look, and tell what you think.

Comment: @mara122 it can be nicely done by either an enum or a `Map<CategoryString, URLString>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197594/discussion-between-mara122-and-andrew-tobilko).

Comment: I dont know wheter you got the alerts about new comments in discussion. Check it out. I have done everything (propably) like you advice.

Comment: @mara122 Well done. Could you show what does the `merlinUrlProperties` class look like? We may improve it as well, if you are interested, of course.

Comment: Sure thing. It looks like this: https://gist.github.com/must1/89456ca2f59813e0d8c1b64847a4c12c

Comment: And what do you think? Is there any way to improve it?

Comment: @mara122 I was curious why you are calling `getMerlin()` on a `MerlinUrlProperties `object. Can you write `@ConfigurationProperties("external.library.url.merlin")` and have those fields in the outer class?

Comment: @mara122 I guess Spring can read everything from `external.library.url.merlin` into a `Map<String, String>` which can help to make things more dynamical. If a new category was added, you would need to change only the yaml file.

Comment: You mean, I should delete the nested class and call field with `merlinUrlProperties.getGuides()` ? If a new category was added, I need to add thsi category to yml file and to put in the map in Source class, not only in yml file.

Comment: @mara122 no, this time you don't populate the map manually. I think you can declare `private Map<String, String> merlin;` and Spring will fill it up for you.

Comment: I'm using enum as a key, so I think it's not gonna work, cuz I think you wanted to add in MerlinUrlProperties `Map<String,String> map = new HashMap...`. Returning to `MerlinUrlProperties` I removed merlin instance so right now I call the properties by `merlinProperties.getGuides`

Comment: Right now it is hard to write integration test for it, right? Before I had test like this: https://github.com/must1/BookstoreScraper/blob/master/src/test/java/bookstore/scraper/booksource/empik/EmpikFetchingBookServiceTest.java I had external file which I could provide by constructor. Now I canot maniuplate with file as I'm passing only category type. Is it possible to write integration test for it? Or should I mock everything?

Comment: @mara122 it's hard to extend when a new category appears - you will have to modify the java code and re-compile it (since a new field will be added as well as a corresponding getter/setter). What I was suggesting is a bit more flexible because you can keep the java code untouched and change only the metadata (here, the YAML file). Why do you need `merlin.getGuides()` if you can do `merlin.get("guides")`?

Comment: ye, but isn't it better idea to keep key as an enum? I mean `Bookstore.EMPIK` is for me much more cleaner. I do not know if it is a better approach. Could you help me with this test? Cuz I do not if it is good idea to mock everything inside the class. The test looks much more harder right now to do rather than before.

Comment: @mara122 Ask a separate question referring to this one. There are people more competent at writing tests than I am. This question I think is over. We flooded enough here.

Comment: Thanks anyway for help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the [Chain Of Responsibility](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility) pattern and allow services to fetch and put the results to the result `Map` object. Also let the Spring to make some magic with autowiring Services by providing some common interface

```
public interface FetchingService {
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> fetchAndAddToResult(Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> result, CategoryType category);
}

@Service
public class EmpikFetchingBookService implements FetchingService  {

    // ...

    @Override
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> fetchAndAddToResult(Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> result, CategoryType category) {
        result.put(Bookstore.EMPIK, getListOfBooks(category));
        return result;
    }
}

@Service
public class MerlinFetchingBookService implements FetchingService  {

    // ...

    @Override
    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> fetchAndAddToResult(Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> result, CategoryType category) {
        result.put(Bookstore.MERLIN, getListOfBooks(category));
        return result;
    }
}

@Service
@Slf4j
public class CategorizedBookService {
    private final List<FetchingService> services;
    //JSoup connector and Properties move to FetchingServices because it is part of those services implementation

    @Autowired
    public CategorizedBookService(List<FetchingService> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> get15BooksByCategory(CategoryType category) {
        Map<Bookstore, List<Book>> result = new HashMap<>();
        for(FetchingService service : services) {
            result = service.fetchAndAddToResult(result, category);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still I don't get it, you just moved everything to Merlin/Empik Fetchers. How am I supposed to choose which link should be chosen based on given category? I updated EmpikFetchingBookService in question.

Comment: What does it mean `How am I supposed to choose which link should be chosen based on given category`? That's responsibility of the specific service to understand how to get the data for specific category - you can introduce some kind of map for every implementation of `FetchingService` or even Factory implementation that will deal with it

Comment: It means that I still do not know how it should be done. Could you introduce just a sample of one category? I have updated question with EmpikFetchingBookService with a method responsible for scraping data from given Document.

Comment: I don't know wheter this way is good: https://gist.github.com/must1/e992a859589554b8025e9aa6e3eccc27

Comment: yup - that's the most naive implementation but that's what I mean - you can put URLs to map with a key of `CategoryType`. BTW you don't need to compare `Enum` values by `equals` - just use simple `categoryTye == categoryType.CRIME`

Comment: Tha's what I want to avoid, the naive implementation, because if I will have 10 categories then this method will be so long.

Answer (score 0):

1) Split into two different services.

2) I believe it worth to use pagination instead of `get15` methods.

3) Instead of having `getRomantic` , `getCrime` you can have:

```
class Service {

private final Map<String,String> categoryToUrl = new HashMap<>();

public Service(){
categoryToUrl.put("crime","http://....");
}

... fetchBook(String category) {
String url = categoryToUrl.get(category);
return fetchUsingJsoap(url);
}

}
```